# Facebook application - prevent recent activity posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a facebook iframe/canvas PHP based application that I want my users to be able to install and use in a completely discreet mode.

However, when the user first installs the application a Recent activity post appears on his facebook wall "user xxx started using app_name" which is visible to all his friends.

Is there a programmatic way or some FB application settings that I can use, so that such a post is avoided ? I should note that the application only requests the basic FB permissions and does not ask for publish_stream permissions.

Alternatively is there a way to use the FB API to delete the recent activity posing?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do it with the API, but you can configure it in the application settings.

To do so, edit your apps settings (http://www.facebook.com/developers/ , choose your app, "Edit Settings" link), then in Facebook Integration tab, disable the "Social Discovery".

Eg: "If social discovery is enabled, Facebook may highlight a user's usage of your application in News Feed and other places to help the user's friends discover your application."

Happy facebook coding!

Comment: Patrick, I know this is a very old thread but see your still around. I'm trying to do the oposite and that is to make my app show "user has started using X" even with Social Discovery enabled it's not showing anything on user's stream/wall. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461628/post-mini-status-update-to-users-wall