# Post mini-status update to user's wall

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've successfully implemented Facebook Connect (using Javascript SDK) on my site and now would like to have a message appear on the user's wall showing they have started using application **X**.

For example RockMelt shows such a thing as in the below picture:

[image]

Is this a simple [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) I need to request for? I've tried `public_stream` but doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

these are auto-generated by facebook for fb apps that have the social-discovery option enabled.  u can find that settings in your dev app.

Comment: Ahh I see. I've checked the App settings and it seems Social Discovery is already enabled, yet it isn't showing up on anyone's wall?

Comment: Is your app in sandbox mode ? If so, I'm not sure facebook will publish these.

Comment: Sandbox mode is disabled. Very odd :/